# Xamarin SketchesでXamarin.FormsのXAMLをプレビューする方法

Tags: xamarin

Xamarin Studio 5.6.3 build 3のSketches機能を使っています。
Xamarin.Formsモードでの利用時にXAMLファイルをプレビューできると良いのですが、残念ながらこのような機能は提供されていないようです。

良い方法はありませんか?

Answer (score 5):

Xamarin.Forms内のメソッドが提供するXAMLローダをリフレクションによって利用することで実現できます。
以下のコードをSketchesのテキストエリアへ貼り付けてください。

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

var xaml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns=""http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"" x:Class=""XamlSamples.HelloXamlPage""
             Title=""Hello XAML Page""
             Padding=""10, 40, 10, 10"">

  <Label Text=""Hello, XAML Sketch!!""
         VerticalOptions=""Start""
         XAlign=""Center""
         Rotation=""15""
         IsVisible=""true""
         Font=""Bold, 80""
         TextColor=""Red"" />

</ContentPage>";

var page = new ContentPage{Padding = new Thickness(0,20,0,0)};
var s = (((MethodInfo)(((TypeInfo)((Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, Version=1.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"))
    .GetTypes().Where(t => t.FullName == "Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions").First()))).DeclaredMembers
    .Where(t => !((MethodInfo)t).Attributes.HasFlag(System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Family)).First())).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(ContentPage))).Invoke(null, new object[]{page, xaml}) != null;
RootPage.Children.Add(page);
```

これを貼り付けると、Xamarin Android PlayerまたはiOS SimulatorでXAMLの解釈されたビューを表示できます。

その後は、XAML部分を編集した結果が即時更新されていきます。

ここでのXAML記述について、`"`を`""`と表記する必要があることに注意してください。

なお、動作の仕組みは[第五次Xamarin.Forms戦争の記録(XAMLのライブプレビュー編)](http://www.muo.jp/2014/12/xamarinformsxaml.html) で紹介されています。